# Display Media files in ListView, NullPointerException?

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception, android-mediaplayer

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private List<String> myList;
File file;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    Log.i("MEDIA", "A");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.i("MEDIA", "B");
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    myList = new ArrayList<String>();

    Log.i("MEDIA", "C");
    File directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    file = new File(directory + "/Test");
    File list[] = file.listFiles();

    Log.i("MEDIA", "D");
    //for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Log.i("MEDIA", "D1"); //CRASHES HERE
        //myList.add(list[i].getName());
        myList.add(list[i].getName());
        Log.i("MEDIA", "D2");
    }

    Log.i("MEDIA", "E");
    final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter); 
    // Set all the file in the list.
}

private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> 
  {

    HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,List<String> objects) 
    {
      super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
      for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) 
      {
        mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
      String item = getItem(position);
      return mIdMap.get(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() 
    {
      return true;
    }

  }
}
```

Log: http://pastebin.com/WWmqKKvQ

I've picked the answer form this question on SO:
[How to show audio files in a listview in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782168/how-to-show-audio-files-in-a-listview-in-android)

Andhave also tried this tutorial:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/

Comment: thats part of the ArrayAdapter mentioned in an example on GoogleDev-Site. I it gives the same error if I use the answer mentioned here:http://stackoverflow.com/a/9784844/2534694

Comment: Does the Test Dir exist under external storage?

Comment: @Mobility Ah yes! Thats where the prb lies. Im testing it on a GalaxyTab, the path is /storage/emulated/0/ ; what changes do I make to point towards this?

Comment: also, do i need to add any permissions for this?

Comment: You need permission to access External Storage in your AppManifest file. Then getExternalStorageDir() and you can browse to the desired directory.

Comment: @Mobility at work, will give it a shot once i get back. :)

Answer (score 1):

The probem was that "/Test" directory does not exist, so i replaced it with "/Bluetooth" (which is a dir that exists) , and now it displays a list of files in that folder.

Problem solved. :D

```
    Log.i("MEDIA", "C");
    File directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    file = new File(directory+ "/Bluetooth");// + "/Test");
    File list[] = file.listFiles();
```